# JCIFS Package Reference Error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ant, jcifs

I am trying to use `JCIFS` to access file in a shared folder and it works perfectly fine using a `java` program. But when I try to use this code in a `javascript` which is embedded in a `ant` script file I get the below error. I do see the `jcifs-1.3.17.jar` in the *classpath* of `ANT` but still it is complaining of *reference error* (**`ReferenceError: "jcifs" is not defined.`**).

Appreciate your inputs/thoughts on this. Thanks in Advance!!!

```
2014-07-17 11:41:32,739 ERROR org.apache.bsf.BSFManager - Exception :
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: org.apache.bsf.BSFException: JavaScript Error: Internal Error: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: **ReferenceError: "jcifs" is not defined.**
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:255)
    at org.apache.bsf.BSFManager.exec(BSFManager.java:491)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.ScriptRunner.executeScript(ScriptRunner.java:100)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Script.execute(Script.java:52)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: org.apache.bsf.BSFException: JavaScript Error: Internal Error: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "jcifs" is not defined.
    at org.apache.bsf.engines.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.handleError(JavaScriptEngine.java:195)
    at org.apache.bsf.engines.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.eval(JavaScriptEngine.java:147)
    at org.apache.bsf.util.BSFEngineImpl.exec(BSFEngineImpl.java:141)
    at org.apache.bsf.BSFManager$6.run(BSFManager.java:493)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:251)
    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Need to preface the package name with Packages.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scripting_Java#External_Packages_and_Classes